# What area is most favorable to subsistence gardening for a vegan diet?

Tags: veganism, subsistence-farming

Meeting all the dietary requirements of a vegan diet is difficult, what area or location is most favorable to substance gardening for a vegan diet?

In other words, if I am moving so I can subsistence farm without the use of electrically supported greenhouses, grow lights & synthetic fertilizers. Where in the world would my best choices be and what specifically should I look for?

Comment: This question might get a better answer on [Gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of parts of the world where it is *possible* to subsistence farm.  The quickest and easiest way to see if a region is friendly to farming is to pull up Google Maps, look at the area, and see if the area is carpeted with farms.  If, outside the cities, the vast majority of the land is occupied by farms, then that area is going to be very friendly to subsistence farming, and even a novice should be able to make a passable go at supplying his/her food needs with farming, assuming access to educational and information resources and plenty of time to devote to it.

For an example of a part of the world that is very friendly to farming, look at a satellite image of rural parts of most US Midestern States (Illinois, Iowa, Indiana).  It'll look like a patchwork quilt where all the patches are individual farms.